# How to translate i18n messages at TinyMCE's user interface in Plone 5?

Tags: internationalization, tinymce, plone, plone-5.x

As title, for example, as below image
[image]

In plone 5, TinyMCE is included mockup, but I can't find any .pot or .po file to translate TinyMCE related messages.

Have any suggestions?

Comment: I fear it can't be translated right now. Seems it's hardcoded inside the `image.xml` file on mockup package. See https://github.com/plone/mockup/blob/6f1019def174c5cbeef79d7e19fafd6f68f1ecf2/mockup/patterns/tinymce/templates/image.xml